# filter listview by header using custom adapter extend baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, filter

My listview looks like this:

--Name(String)-- --Money(int)--- ---Years(int)----

I want to filter this listview by Name or by Money or By Year. 
I can add on each colum a ImageView like a arrow up or down to call a onClickListener to make the listview filter.

take a look on the picture below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHVla.png)
According to the picture when click on Img1 => filter by Name , Img2 => filter by money...

**And here the adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Items> items;

public Adapter (Activity activity, List<Items> items){
    this.activity=activity;
    this.items =items;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(inflater==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_row,null);
    }


        TextView name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.acname);
        TextView money=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ac_money);
        TextView year=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ac_year);

    Items item=items.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());

        money.setText(item.getMoney());

        year.setText(item.getYear());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Thanks for help

Comment: How do name, money and years get mapped to the listitems in `getView()` in your listadapter? What is the underlying datastructure (database, collection, etc.)? Could you post your `getView()` method?

Comment: I Edit the post Micha F. thanks for help

Comment: Wait, you write "filter" - I thought you meant how to sort the respective columns, because thats what such arrows usually are for: to sort the respective column either ascending or descending. Did I answer your question with my post? Or did you mean something different?

Comment: Hello Micha F. Excuz for delay. Let try and get you back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Item` Class, add following inner classes (comparators):

```
static class NameComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
}

static class MoneyComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        return a.getMoney().compareTo(b.getMoney);
    }
}

static class YearComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        return a.getYear().compareTo(b.getYear);
    }
}
```

In your adapter, you can add following methods:

```
public void sortByName(boolean descending) {
    Collections.sort(items, new Item.NameComparator());
    if (descending) Collections.reverse(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void sortByMoney(boolean descending) {
    Collections.sort(items, new Item.MoneyComparator());
    if (descending) Collections.reverse(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void sortByYear(boolean descending) {
    Collections.sort(items, new Item.YearComparator());
    if (descending) Collections.reverse(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you can call these methods in the `onClick()` methods of the arrows.

Comment: Hello Micha F. many thanks. it's amazing. It's work good. thanks a lot.

Comment: Cheers. If my answer solved your problem, you could tick it to show so, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By using Collections.sort()method and after that call  notifyDataSetChanged().